# Is it possible to pass variable from steps to script in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have one pipeline and I want to pass one Arraylist that I get from a groovy method into the script that is running in Master Jenkins.

```
stages {
        stage('Get Tests Parameter') {
            steps {
                code = returnList()
                script {
                    properties([
                            parameters([
                                    [$class              : 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
                                     choiceType          : 'PT_CHECKBOX',
                                     description         : 'Select a choice',
                                     defaultValue        : '',
                                     filterLength        : 1,
                                     filterable          : false,
                                     name                : 'Tests',
                                     referencedParameters: 'role',
                                     script              : [$class        : 'GroovyScript',
                                                            fallbackScript: [
                                                                    classpath: [],
                                                                    sandbox  : true,
                                                                    script   : 'return ["ERROR"]'
                                                            ],
                                                            script        : [
                                                                    classpath: [],
                                                                    sandbox  : false,
                                                                    script   : code
                                                            ]
                                     ]
                                    ]
                            ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
}
...

def returnList() {
    def stringList = []
    def fileContent = readFile "/var/jenkins_home/example.txt"
    for (line in fileContent.readLines()) {
        stringList.add(line.split(",")[0] + ":selected");
    }
    return stringList
}
```

That stages are running in a slave, so I couldn't execute that method *returnList()* inside the script because the script is running in Master. So I'm trying to get *returnList* ArrayList to a variable and use that variable in the script part.
Is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK all Pipeline Groovy Code runs on  Master, where does the assumption that the method would run on the agent come from? Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried to pass the code in the script block of the parameters and that didn't recognize the file. So I suppose that the script block of the properties parameters runs on the master

Comment: is your `example.txt` on maste or agent?

Comment: you can not pass the arraylist as an object to that `script` parameter, you have to pass the *text* of a groovy script.

Comment: My example.txt is on slave

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a specific step in a specific node then you can specify the agent within the stage block. So what you can do is execute the file reading logic on the master in the initial stage and then use it in consecutive stages. Check the example below.

```
def code

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('LoadParameters') {
            agent { label 'master' }
            steps {
                 scipt {
                    code = returnList()
                  }
            }
        }
        stage('Get Tests Parameter') {
            steps {
                script {
                    properties([
                            parameters([
                                    [$class              : 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
                                     choiceType          : 'PT_CHECKBOX',
                                     description         : 'Select a choice',
                                     defaultValue        : '',
                                     filterLength        : 1,
                                     filterable          : false,
                                     name                : 'Tests',
                                     referencedParameters: 'role',
                                     script              : [$class        : 'GroovyScript',
                                                            fallbackScript: [
                                                                    classpath: [],
                                                                    sandbox  : true,
                                                                    script   : 'return ["ERROR"]'
                                                            ],
                                                            script        : [
                                                                    classpath: [],
                                                                    sandbox  : false,
                                                                    script   : code
                                                            ]
                                     ]
                                    ]
                            ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def returnList() {
    def stringList = []
    def fileContent = readFile "/var/jenkins_home/example.txt"
    for (line in fileContent.readLines()) {
        stringList.add(line.split(",")[0] + ":selected");
    }
    return stringList
}
```